# Would it be possible to change this Nodejs function to server and accept post data

Tags: node.js, http-post

basically as the title says I need help changing my node.js script to a server that accepts post data
I am new to node and I am struggling

here is what I have so far

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var value = process.argv[2];
var value1 = process.argv[3];

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
  sys.puts(stdout)
};

exec("casperjs test.js " + value + " " + value1 , puts);
```

can any one help me convert this from command line

```
node node.js value value1
```

to a http server that I can accept postdata 
just an example

```
Localhost.com:8080/value=data+value1=data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [querystring](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module in node to parse GET parameters. Then you can feed those parameters into your exec call.

Comment: @tsturlz could ypu please show me an example on how I can do this please I am new to node : )

Comment: There are plenty. Start with nodes documentation as I linked above. Also there are plenty of posts on this already. Use the url module to parse the url, take the "search" property of the returned object and parse that with querystring. Please read the documentation and use google.